# Prove that the one of them defines a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at the following:

"We are given the following two mappings, which are related to the rings $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$: $f_1([a]_{10})=[3a]_{40}$ and $f_2([a]_{10})=[8a]_{40}$. Prove that the one of them defines a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{40}$, while the other one does not define a similar group homomorphism. For this $f_i$, for which the answer was positive, answer the following: Which is its kern, which is its image, if it is a group monomorphism and if it is a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{40}$."

$$$$

To check which of them defines a group homomorphism, I do the following:

$$f_1([a]_{10})=[3a]_{40} , \ \ \ f_1([b]_{10})=[3b]_{40} \Rightarrow f_1([a+b]_{10})=[3(a+b)]_{40} \\ f_1([a]_{10}) + f_1([b]_{10})=[3a]_{40} + [3b]_{40}=[3(a+b)]_{40} \\ \text{ So, since } f_1([a+b]_{10})=f_1([a]_{10}) + f_1([b]_{10}), f_1 \text{ defines a group homomorfism. }$$

$$f_2([a]_{10})=[8a]_{40} , \ \ \ f_2([b]_{10})=[8b]_{40} \Rightarrow f_2([a+b]_{10})=[8(a+b)]_{40} \\ f_2([a]_{10}) + f_2([b]_{10})=[8a]_{40} + [8b]_{40}=[8(a+b)]_{40} \\ \text{ So, since } f_2([a+b]_{10})=f_2([a]_{10}) + f_2([b]_{10}), f_2 \text{ defines a group homomorfism. }$$

But I have to show that only one of them defines a group homomorphism.

What have I done wrong??

Comment: Hint: Consider $[0]_10 = [10]_10$. What are $f_1([10]_10)$ and $f_2([10]_10)$?

Comment: $$[10]_{10}=[0]_{10}$$ $$f_1([10]_{10})=[3 \cdot 10]_{40}=[30]_{40} \neq [0]_{40}=f_1([0]_{10})$$
$$f_2([10]_{10})=[8 \cdot 10]_{40}=[80]_{40} =[0]_{40}=f_2([0]_{10})$$
So $f_2$ defines a group homomorphism, but $f_1$ doesn't.. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, because $f_1$ is not well-defined, which it has to be before it can be a homomorphism.

Comment: I'd like some confirmation from someone else, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1$ is not well-defined.

Consider $[0]_{10} = [10]_{10}$.
But $f_1([0]_{10}) = [3\times0]_{40} = [0]_{40}$ and 
$f_1([10]_{10}) = [3\times10]_{40} = [30]_{40} \ne [0]_{40}$.

Thus, $f_1([0]_{10}) \ne f_1([10]_{10}) \Rightarrow$ $f_1$ is not well-defined, and therefore not a homomorphism.

Alternatively, you could just argue that $[10]_{10}$ is the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ but $f_1([10]_{10}) = [30]_{40}$ is *not* the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$, so $f_1$ cannot be a homomorphism, as homomorphisms map the identity to the identity.

Comment: Ahaa!! Ok!! I understand!!! $$\\$$
As for the other questions:
$$\text{ Which is its kern:} Ker(f_2)=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}: f([a]_{10})=[0]_{40} \}=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}: [8a]_{40}=[0]_{40} \}=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}: 40 \mid 8a \}=\{5,10,15, \dots \}$$
$$\text{ Which is its image: } Im(f_2)=\{ f([a]_{10}) \}=\{[8a]_{40} \}$$
$$\text{ Is it a group monomorphism?: No, because } Ker(f_2) \neq \{0 \}$$
$$\text{ Is it a ring homomorphism? For this do I have to check if } f_2([a]_{10}+[b]_{10})=f_2([a]_{10})+f_2([b]_{10}) \text{ AND } f_2([a]_{10}*[b]_{10})=f_2([a]_{10})*f_2([b]_{10}) ?$$

Comment: Are my answers corrert??

Comment: A small correction: It is just $\lbrace [0]_{10}, [5]_{10} \rbrace$ (remember, $[0]_{10} = [10]_{10} = \ldots$ and $[5]_{10} = [15]_{10} = \ldots$).

Comment: Yes, to check whether it is a ring homomorphism, you have to check both conditions.

Comment: Aha! Ok!! $$ \\ $$ What about the answers for the questions about the image and the group monomorphism? Are they correct?? $$ \\ $$ $$f_2([a]_{10}+[b]_{10})=f_2([a+b]_{10})=[8(a+b)]_{40}=[8a]_{40}+[8b]_{40}$$
$$f_2([a]_{10} \cdot [b]_{10})=f_2([a \cdot b]_{10})=[8(a \cdot b)]_{40} \neq [8a]_{40} \cdot [8b]_{40}$$
So it is not a ring homomorphism.. Is this correct??

Comment: @MaryStar I think you can, and should, describe the structure of the $\text{Im}(f_2)$ in more detail. It has only a few elements. And yes, it is not a monomorphism as the kernel is non-trivial. The number of elements in the kernel should also tell you about the number of elements in the image!

Comment: @MaryStar Also, you should first show that $f_2$ is well-defined (unlike $f_1$).

Comment: To show that $f_2$ is well-defined, do I have to do it in the same way I showed that $f_1$ is not well-defined?? I mean:
$$[10]_{10}=[0]_{10}$$
$$f_2([10]_{10})=[8a]_{40}=[80]_{40}=[0]_{40}=f_2([0]_{10})$$??

Comment: @MaryStar No, to prove that it *is* well-defined, you have to prove it in general. Show that if $[m]_{10} = [n]_{10}$, then $f_2([m]_{10}) = f_2([n]_{10})$. So you have to specify exactly when it is that $[m]_{10} = [n]_{10}$.

Comment: Ahaa..Ok! Thank you very much!!! :-)